# what is use of loadlayout and renderlayout and what can they do?

Tags: php, function, magento, controller, magento-1.9

what is loadlayout() and renderlayout() do ?
in controller'S Function

```
 public function viewAction()
 {
 $this->loadLayout();
 $this->renderLayout();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->renderLayout();` get layout output and process this output to response body and append response

`$this->loadLayout();` creates XML tree at backend.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the loadLayout method of your Action Controller, Magento will

1. Instantiate a Block class for each  tag, looking up the class using the tag's type attribute as a global config path and store it in the internal _blocks array of the layout object, using the tag's name attribute as the array key.
2. If the  tag contains an output attribute, its value is added to the internal _output array of the layout object.

Then, when you call the renderLayout method in your Action Controller,
Magento will iterate over all the Blocks in the _output array, using the value of the output attribute as a callback method.

This is always toHtml, and means the starting point for output will be that Block's Template.

Cheers ;-)